# Entity Framework - Fluent Api - Save The Child Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Imagine the following simple context -

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int TeacherId {get;set;}
    public virtual Teacher Teacher {get;set;}
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int RoomId {get;set;}
    public virtual Room ClassRoom {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get;set;}
}

public class Room
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers {get;set;}
}
```

All relationships are laid out correctly in my `DbContext`.

Knowing the `TeacherId` (let's use `teacherId == 1` as an example), I would only like to save the `Student` object.

When I map my simple dto to my entity, the `Teacher` and `Room` objects both have default values, which means the `Id` property in those two objects are set to 0. As the result, When I `DbSet.Save(student)`, I'm getting a FK constraint violation exception eventhough, I'm setting the `Student.TeacherId = 1`.

How can I only save the child object without having the need to save the parent objects?

Comment: Seems like the virtual properties should just be null instead of initialized to default values if they aren't really loaded

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: *When I map my simple dto to my entity* - looks like it is problematic code which you have omitted.